# I want to do when I click on one div then it hides other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is working till div8 but doesn't work after div8 why is this happening please help me out
and one more thing plz also explain it if you correct this code and this problem coming because this method doesn't work for more div sorry I know this is silly question. Thanks in advance

```
  <div style="flex: 1">
        <label class="ac_trigger" for="ac1">Sweets</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ac_hide"  onclick="showHide(this,'div1')" id="ac1" name="x1">
      </div>
      <div class="ac_container" id="div1">
        {% for a,b in sweets.items %}
        <table class="foods">
          <tr>
            <th id="{{b}}">{{b}}</th><td><input type="number" name="{{a}}" value="0" id="{{a}}"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        {% endfor %}      
      </div>

..................so on to below one.............

      <div style="flex: 1">
        <label class="ac_trigger" for="ac35">Vegitables</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ac_hide"  onclick="showHide(this,'div35')" id="ac35" name="x1">
      </div>
      <div class="ac_container" id="div35">
        {% for a,b in veg.items %}
        <table class="foods">
          <tr>
            <th id="{{b}}">{{b}}</th><td><input type="number" name="{{a}}" value="0" id="{{a}}"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        {% endfor %}      
      </div>
     </div> 


    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function showHide(tagData, divId){
    let allInputs = ['ac1','ac2','ac3','ac4','ac5','ac6','ac7','ac8','ac9','ac10','ac11','ac12','ac13','ac14','ac15','ac16','ac17','ac18','ac19','ac20','ac21','ac22','ac23','ac24','ac25','ac26','ac27','ac28','ac29','ac30','ac31','ac32','ac33','ac34','ac35'];
   let divToChange = document.getElementById(divId);
   divToChange.style.display = tagData.checked ? "block" : "none";
   if(tagData.checked){
   for(let i = 0 ; i = allInputs.length ; i++){
     if(tagData.id !== allInputs[i]) {
       let divToHideId = 'div'+allInputs[i].substr(allInputs[i].length - 1)
       document.getElementById(divToHideId).style.display = 'none'
       document.getElementById(allInputs[i]).checked = false
     }
   }
   }
   
  };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing something there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showHide(tagData, divId){
    let allInputs = ['ac1','ac2','ac3','ac4','ac5','ac6','ac7','ac8','ac9','ac10','ac11','ac12','ac13','ac14','ac15','ac16','ac17','ac18','ac19','ac20','ac21','ac22','ac23','ac24','ac25','ac26','ac27','ac28','ac29','ac30','ac31','ac32','ac33','ac34','ac35'];
    let divToChange = document.getElementById(divId);
    divToChange.style.display = tagData.checked ? "block" : "none";
    if(tagData.checked){

      //TRY TO USE for(let i = 0;i<=allInputs.length;i++)

      for(let i = 0 ; i = allInputs.length ; i++){
        if(tagData.id !== allInputs[i]) {
          let divToHideId = 'div'+allInputs[i].substr(allInputs[i].length - 1)
          document.getElementById(divToHideId).style.display = 'none'
          document.getElementById(allInputs[i]).checked = false
        }
      }
    }
        
  };

</script>
```

Comment: no bro its not working plzz help me resolve it

Comment: because if u look at the div tag, u are assigning id="ac1", so it is impossible for you to access using showHide(this,"div1").

Try changing the parameter to the one below.
onclick="showHide(this,'ac1')"

Comment: onclick="showHide(this,'ac1')"  it is not working then or plzz you can suggest any other method to do this whole function

Answer (score 0):

function which we required for this question
i am very happy right now.....best regards for others

```
function showHide(evt, divId) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("ac_container");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("ac_hide");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```